# Access Denied when moving Folder from a document library (which have content approval on) to another list (which does not have content approval on)

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, permissions, move-to

We have 2 Document Libraries inside our classic online team site, as follow:-

1. Lib A which have content approval on.
2. Lib B which have content approval off.

Now if a user with contribute permission on both libraries tried to move a folder from LibA to LibB using the modern "Move to" feature, the user will get this error "Access denied.You Do not have Permission to perform this action or access this resource":-

[image]

While using the site admin user, i am able to Move the folder.. any advice on this weird behavior?
Thanks

Comment: check out this [article](https://cann0nf0dder.wordpress.com/2019/04/13/access-denied-when-attempting-to-move-sharepoint-documents/) and also [this](https://mydigitalworkplace.wordpress.com/2018/05/20/10-things-about-copy-and-move-sharepoint-online/)

Comment: @MatiurRahman thanks for the usful links... i were not expecting this strange behavior, that DL with content approval ON , will not allow contributors to move files... and that you must be site admin!!!! WOW

Answer (score 1):

Two workarounds for your reference:

1. Change the Draft item security in library A:(This only applies to libA has content approval on, libB has content approval off)

[image]

2. Create a **new permission level** based on **Contribute** and append "Approve items" to it:
   (This will works well if libB also has content approval on)

[image]